# How to extract multiple polygons from a layer that overlap with a point?

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, iteration

I would like to get attributes of polygons that overlap with a point. This is to see on which street the lanterns are located, so if they are on a crossing I want to get both streets.

Right now I can only get the first street it encounters, and I can't find a way to iterate over the different polgyons.

Anyone that can help?

Comment: what would you want to do with those attributes, e.g. simply select them to inspect or add them to the attribute table of your lanterns or export? and is there only one point, or do you want the process run on a layer of lanterns and collect attributes for each one?

Comment: I would like to add the street name(s) to the lanterns so that I know on which street(s) each lantern is located and then later can select/filter them based on that attribute. So if it is on a crossing it must have both street names, and if it's not only one. 
There are multiple streets and multiple lanterns, and I want to run the process on all lanterns I have in my layer (so your second suggestion).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something you can do with "join attributes by location (1:n)". Which version of QGIS are you using?

In QGIS 3.2 you will find an extra option within the "join attributes by location" processing tool for one to many joins. Use your lanterns as the input layer and your polygons as the join layer. In the fields to add option choose the attributes you want to add from your polygon layer. Next select the one-to-many as the join. This will create a new layer of points with separate point for each located feature from the polygon layer.

e.g.

Lantern 1+polygon feature 1 attributes

Lantern 1+polygon feature 2 attributes

etc.

[image: Join attributes by location]

Comment: better post this as a comment...

Comment: I don't have enough rep yet to do that yet unfortunately, will do soon.

Comment: ah yeah...damn. it shall be excused, then ,) don´t forget to edit the answer once you got enough information. answers of this format will likely get deleted otherwise...

Comment: btw. I think you can savely assume those functions haven´t changed much since QGIS 2.0...or have they?

Comment: They have, QGIS 3.2 gained the 1:n version so my anwers would be a QGIS 3.2 specific one.

Comment: ...I use and contribute to QGIS professionally since 10 years now and I was simply assuming this function was there all the time...shame on me. nonetheless, offer that solution with the note to the version dependancy maybe; better than the one liner. and my +1 is guaranteed ,)

Comment: Updated my answer, hope I explained that sufficiently? Perhaps I should've mentioned that, given its points, you could use "within"?  "Intersects" would work fine though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of options (and built in tools/toolchains); I personally like the power and versatility of SQL.
One thing to consider is how to store multiple road names in one column, since you say you want to later select by that attribute; while using QGIS' natively supported *SpatiaLite* SQL dialect, the options are primarily reduced to a string 'array', though.

**Option 1: *Virtual Layers*:**

- open the *Virtual Layer* from `<QGIS> | Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

  - `Import` both of your layers (in the top panel)
  - run (paste and hit `Add` in the bottom panel):

    ```
    SELECT lnt.*,
           group_concat(rds.name) AS roads
    FROM <lantern_layer_name> AS lnt
    LEFT JOIN <roads_layer_name> AS rds
      ON ST_Intersects(lnt.geometry, rds.geometry)
    GROUP BY lnt.<unique_id>;
    ```
  - `Close` the *Virtual Layer* dialog
- save the added layer to e.g. *Shapefile* (`<context_menu> | Save as...`)

**Option 2: *DB Manager*:**

- open `<QGIS> | Database | DB Manager...`

  - double-click `Virtual Layers | Project layers` (left panel)
  - open `SQL Window` (top bar, 2nd symbol from left)
  - run (paste and hit `Execute` in the top panel):
    **`<same query as above>`**
  - tick `Load as new Layer`

    - choose `Geoemtry column` and `Layer name`
    - hit `Load`
- save layer to file

Both options will add a layer with an additional `roads` column to the attributes of the lantern layer with all intersecting road's names as strings, delimited by a `,`.